# Commutator of the unit object, in a symmetric monoidal category.

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,\phi,\psi,U)$ be a symmetric monoidal category, where $\otimes:\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ is a bifunctor. Let $X,Y,Z \in \mathcal{C}$, then $\phi:(X \otimes Y) \otimes Z \overset{\simeq}{\to} X \otimes (Y \otimes Z)$ is the **associator**, and $\psi:X \otimes Y \overset{\simeq}{\to} Y \otimes X$ is the **commutator**,where both $\phi,\psi$ are subject to some coherence conditions (pentagon & hexagon-axioms, see e.g. chap. $1$ "Tannakian Categories" by P. Deligne &  J.S. Milne). Furthermore, $U$ is the unit object.

In "Catégories Tannakiennes" by Saavedro Rivano (specifically, see $2.3.1,2.3.2$ on page $38$) there is a claim that one has $\psi_{U,U} = \text{id}_{U \otimes U}$.

It is furthermore said, I believe, that this follows from the commutativity of the diagram

[image]

$\underline{Note}$: I have reinterpreted Saavedro Rivano:s notation to be consistent with P. Deligne & J.S. Milne:s notation.

Here, $r_{X} := \psi_{U,X} \circ l_X$ where $l_X:X \overset{\simeq}{\to} U \otimes X$ for each object $X \in \mathcal{C}$.

I tried (perhaps naively) to show this by setting $X = U$ in the diagram, but this gives you (trivially) that $l_{U} = l_{U}$, since $\psi_{U,U} \circ r_U = l_{U} \iff  \psi_{U,U} \circ (\psi_{U,U} \circ l_{U}) = l_{U} \iff l_{U} = l_{U}$ since $\psi_{U,U}^2 = \text{id}_{U \otimes U}$.

Comment: There is a whole article devoted to unit objects in symmetric monoidal categories: Kock, Joachim Elementary remarks on units in monoidal categories.  Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc.  144  (2008),  no. 1, 53--76. "We explore an alternative definition of unit in a monoidal category originally due to Saavedra: a Saavedra unit is a cancellable idempotent (in a 1-categorical sense). This notion is more economical than the usual notion..."

Comment: Given a unit $(U,u)$ in the sense of Saavedra, one shows that there are unique natural isomorphisms $\lambda_X$ and $\rho_X$ such that $\lambda_U=u=\rho_U$. I believe this is in Saavedra. If not, it is surely in Kock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the fact that $r_U=l_U$. Mac Lane takes this as an additional axiom (item $(8)$ as shown below) in his treatment of (symmetric, braided or vanilla) monoidal categories but it can be shown superfluous, following from other things. Then $\psi_{U,U}r_U=l_U=r_U$ and $r_U$ is an isomorphism, so...

By superfluous, I mean items $(4)-(7)$ suffice to prove item $(8)$.

[image: Screengrab from CWM]

You realise this by solving exercise $(9)$ and then considering: [image: Sketch]

Comment: It follows from which theorem that $r_{U} = l_{U}$?

Comment: @Ben123 Oh no, I meant "the theorem $r_U=l_U$". It is a theorem (or part of the definition...) that $r_U=l_U$ holds.

Comment: Oh, and you mean that Maclane take that as an additional axiom, but that the axiom is superflous? Do you have a reference for a proof of $r_{U} = l_{U}$?

Comment: @Ben123 I don't recall exactly where I first saw this stated. There are various posts on MSE or MO about minor inaccuracies, e.g. he misstates the braiding axioms too. I have my own notes but these aren't available... if I remember correctly it follows from the pentagonal axiom and specialising all objects equal to $U$, then plugging $l_U$ or $r_U$ in in an appropriate place. But you can just take it as part of your definition, and then you will be on the same page as everyone else

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying. =) I will probably have to prove it, since I plan on using it, but this atleast explains some missing details (I assume this is part of the justification for the claim $\psi_{U,U} = \text{id}_{U \otimes U}$ in Rivano:s treatment).

Comment: Also, a comment; I don´t think you can "plug" in $l_U$ or $r_U$ anywhere in the pentagon-axiom, since that axiom only involves $\phi$, $\phi \otimes 1$ and $1 \otimes \phi$. But there are some more coherence conditions (I belive they are called so) for $l_U$, perhaps that is what you are referring to (see $1.3.a$ in P. Deligne & J.S. Milne).

Comment: Also, on cursory reading, I can´t find where Maclane states that he takes $r_{U} = l_{U}$ as an axiom (or the equivalent formulation, up to change of notation), in "Categories for the working mathematician".

Comment: @Ben123 By plugging in I meant pre or post composing with some combination of $1$ and $l_U$. I've elaborated with images

Comment: But this is in a monoidal category, not neccessarily in a symmetric monoidal category. P. Deligne & J.S. Milne defines $r_{U} := \psi_{U,U} \circ l_{U}$. So how can $\rho_{a}^{-1} := r_{a}$ if the definition of $r_{a}$ involves the commutator, which we don´t neccessarily have access to. I suppose what one could say is that in a symmetric monoidal category (due to uniqueness of $\psi_{U,X}$ and $l_{X}$; the latter corresponding to $\lambda^{-1}_{X}$ in Maclane) we need $r_{U} \equiv \rho_{a}^{-1}$?

Also, big thanks for the input.

Comment: @Ben123 Symmetric monoidal categories *are* monoidal categories. In which case Deligne has made a definition a priori different from the one I'm used to, which is... unexpected. But I would hope that Deligne's definition coincides with Mac Lanes. Mac Lane defines symmetric monoidal categories as monoidal categories with a symmetry, which is better and more from the ground up, monoidal categories being the more primitive notion.

Comment: Sorry, $\psi$ is not unique, neccessarily, but $l_X$ is. I will investigate this more, but thanks a lot =)